# Positive definite Hessian matrix

Tags: integration, hessian-matrix

1)If I want to prove a Hessian matrix is positive definite and it contains the entries of $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$, can I multiply it also with the same $x$ to simplify my calculations?

2)Is the integral of a strictly convex function a strictly convex function? And why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you rephrase 1), I have no idea what you are asking. Regarding 2), the integral of a function (convex or not) is a number... Are you talking about deciding if the integral is a convex operator?

Comment: @PierreCarre 1) if I have a hessian matrix containing $x_1,...,x_N$ and I want to prove that it's positive definite, i.e $y^THy \gt 0$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R^N}$ and $y \ne 0$. Can I take $x:=(x_1,...,x_N)$ instead of $y$ to simplify my calculations? Or it would be a specific case? 2) I mean if I have $f$ a strictly convex function and $J$ is the composition between $f$ and integral, then would $J$ be also strictly convex?